# PHP function return value to html tag

Tags: php, html

I want to get return value of a function and display it to a specific id.

In my Class.php I have a function named login that validates if the password is correct/incorrect

```
<?php
class Class
{
    public function login()
    {
        if($_POST['password'] == Match) {
            return 'Correct Password!';
        } else {
            return 'Incorrect password!';
        }
    }
}
```

and in my my index.php I have this html. now how can I get the return value of my login function in my html tag with an ID of check

```
<?php
require_once 'Class.php';
$class = new Class();
$class->login();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOMETHING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <span id="check"></span> <!-- I want to put the returned value here -->

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<span id="check"><?php echo $class->login();?></span>`

Comment: But you really should do your own homework

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require_once 'Class.php';
$class = new Class();
$returnedValue = $class->login();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOMETHING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <span id="check"><?= $returnedValue ?></span>

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I have many return values like. Incorrect password, Incorrect username.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the code below, but you can use this logic to achieve your goal.

Your index.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOMETHING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="loginform" action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <span id="check"></span>

        <input type="submit" value="Login"  class="Login">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Your Ajax script (using jquery):

```
 $(function() {
      $("button.Login").click(function(){
              $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "data.php",
              data: $('form.loginform').serialize(),
              success: function(msg){
                 $('#check').html(msg);
                  },
                });
      });
  });
```

Your php file to receive the data (data.php):

```
<?php
require_once 'Class.php';
$class = new Class();
echo $class->login();
?>
```