# how to passing values from php to javascript to html to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

PS: the full code in the end

i have 2 pages.

**php.php**

**js.php**

i sent variables  from **php.php** to **js.php** by using **curl**

```
 function js(){
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL ,"http://localhost/js.php");
 curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST , true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS," ");
 curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $allaa= curl_exec($ch);
 $errorr = curl_error($ch);
 echo $allaa;
 return $allaa; 
 }
```

**js.php** contain **Javascript code**

i passed value that i received from **first page** to **Javascript**  in **second page**

**by this code**

```
 var variable=<?php echo  json_encode($variable); ?>;
```

i made some processes on the  variable
and the result i print it by this code

```
 variable="Hello World";
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "!!!"+variable+"!!!";
```

**js.php** contain

**html code**

```
 <p id="result"> </p>
```

it must the result of **Javascript** appear in the tag like this

```
 <p id="result">!!!Hello World!!! </p>
```

in the **php.php page** 
i stored the **returned value** in **variable x**

and i printed it

```
 $x=js();

 $xb = get_string_between($x, "!!!", "!!!");
 echo xb;
```

the result must be

**Hello World**

but its not 
its

**"+variable+"**

how to fix this problem

new edit this is the code

**php.php  page code**

```
  <?php
  function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
  $string = ' ' . $string;
  $ini = strpos($string, $start);
  if ($ini == 0) return '';
  $ini += strlen($start);
  $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
  return substr($string, $ini, $len);
  }
  function js(){
  ////////////////
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL ,"http://localhost/js.php");
  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST , true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"variable=hello");
  curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $allaa = curl_exec($ch);
  $errorr = curl_error($ch);
  echo  $allaa;
  return $allaa;    
  }

  $ff=js();
  echo $xb = get_string_between($ff, "!!!", "!!!!");
  ?>
```

**js.php page code**

```
  <?php 
  global $variable;

  $variable=$_POST['variable'];

  ?>
  <html>

  <script>
  var variable=<?php echo  json_encode($variable); ?>;
  variable=variable+" world ";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "!!!"+variable+"!!!!";
  </script>
  <p id="result"> </p>

  </html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you try to do it this way?

Comment: yes , the big reason is i want to use a javascript function called JSEncrypt()

its just for javascript 
and i want to process a value from php by this value

i want to proccsess many variables 
and all this in one page without changing the current page

Comment: `!!Hello World!!` has two `!` either side ...  `get_string_between($x, "!!!", "!!!");` looks for **THREE** times `!`  .. `!!` can't be found by looking for `!!!` (P.S. this comment looks like brainf*ck code!!)

Comment: check the code now :)

Comment: I mean is there a reason to use curl? But in javascript you need to define variables with:  var variable="Hello World";

Comment: i think the resone for curl is that i want to do it in one page 
without interrupt the processes by moving from page to page ,and i'm beginner in javascript

Comment: Using jquery it is quite easy. You can send requests to php files like I do here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161485/php-function-return-value-to-html-tag/39162071#39162071 then javascript does the the POST request to PHP and PHP returns it to Javascript, which can then manipulate the DOM (after the success function on that answer)

Comment: i will try ,but it  will fix the problem? i mean get the html value after processing by javascript to get it back to php

Comment: Try reading about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-load-and-document-ready-functions I'm not sure my other link is what you asked for

Answer (score 0):

I think that  script from js.php is not interpreted on server side and you get this script as plain text where between "!!!" is only "+variable+".

Comment: i don't think that ,


i tested it ,


and i opened js.php directly,


it printed the value without any problem.



i think the problem is with displaying the result on the browser 


the result must displayed on the browser but i want to get back the 


value without displaying the value 
,


Thanks.

Comment: How did you open this File and what did you get exactly?

Comment: i know theres a problem executing php + javascript

Comment: directly through the browser 
@TomekB.

Comment: rubbish - you cant put any serverside into javascript

Comment: var variable=<?php echo  json_encode($variable); ?>;
what about this code ?
this code did job pass serverside value to javascript

Comment: While php File is interpreted, server generate js script and send it to The browser where is interpreted and you get printed variable. But the same time script is assigned to your variable $x like simple string.

Comment: If you want you can try use JS Engine for PHP... But i think it unnecessary impediment.

Comment: that is php pure php -

Comment: variable contains

Comment: @TomekB. JS engine ?
i will try to use it 
have links for it ? official site ?

Comment: @jan199674 the problem with response from  javascript to html to php 
not from php to javascript

Comment: oh ya , i will see ,i think  will not fix it but i will try

Comment: server vs browser

Comment: javascript in a php include

Comment: php inside jquery

Answer (score 0):

This question is difficult to answer because it's all broken up and we can't see the full picture. However, I'll try my best to dissect what you're asking. First off, you have this code in **php.php**:

```
function js(){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_URL ,"http://localhost/js.php");
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_POST , true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS," ");
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result= curl_exec($ch);
$errorr = curl_error($ch);
echo $allaa;
return $allaa; 
}
```

I've a few issues with this. First, though not entirely relevant, is that `CURLOPT_URL` can be set with `curl_init()` instead. Second is that you have empty post fields (before your edit it was `$post` which is equally as cryptic). Third, you echo and return a variable called `$allaa`. Nobody knows what this variable is or where is came from.

Anyways, apparently there's a second page you have called **js.php** which contains some JavaScript. Let's assume the correct information was sent over via POST from the `js()` function.

You have somewhere in your **js.php** file code that looks like this:

```
var variable=<?php echo  json_encode($variable); ?>;
```

I'm assuming that this is somewhere between `<script>` tags. So, what is this `$variable`? We have no hint as to what it is. You seem to imply that the desired information from `js()` wound up in `$variable` though. This is where I would question if the correct information is being passed. Also, you're running it through `json_encode()` which probably means there's a double quote in there somewhere. How would JavaScript treat this?

Finally, you attempt to insert the passed variable into HTML by issuing JavaScript that manipulates the DOM:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "!!!"+variable+"!!!";
```

And then for some reason you decided to print it again with PHP:

```
$x=js();

$xb = get_string_between($x, "!!!", "!!!");
echo xb;
```

This brings back the string **+variable+**. The issue here is simple. JavaScript executes on the client-side AFTER the server-side code has executed. So, this code does exactly what you tell it too. **variable** isn't replaced until the browser executes the client-side JavaScript.

Comment: :D thanks for your replay . i fixed the code u can see the full code in the end of my post , is there a way to fix it without browser ? i need the value from javascript to php , the problem is if i decide to display it on browser i will not able to take it back to php because php code will be executed and finished and i want all this in one page

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't use JavaScript at all. It seems pointless. Users can disable JavaScript anyway and some legacy or limited clients don't support it. Why not just keep it in PHP like so?
`<p id="result"><?php echo json_encode($variable); ?></p>`

Comment: cuz there a function just for javascript 
called JSEncrypt()
just for javascript :(

Comment: @MohammedNaji You should never decide the tools you want to use before outlining your problem. It's like saying "I want to use this socket set to shingle the roof". It simply doesn't work. If you looked through some PHP documentation, you would find that there are similar functions. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php