# Submit javascript variable to a database trough php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How could i submit the Javascrip variable called "currentRating" inside the "callback:" so i can get the number of that variable into a Mysql database trough PHP?

I do have the conection and database running with PHP, i just dont know anything about Javascript and i am using a rating system that uses Java and Ajax

```html
<?php
echo
"<script>
$(function() {
  $('.my-rating').starRating({
    initialRating: ". $current_rating .",
    callback: function(currentRating, element){
        window.alert('RATED')
    }
  });
}); 
</script>";?>
```

Comment: You can do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39161485/php-function-return-value-to-html-tag/39162071#39162071

instead of data: $('form.loginform').serialize(), you can do  data; 'current_rating' : $current_rating, and in you php file grab the value with $_POST['current_rating']

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an ajax call, that is to call to a php page listening for the currentRating variable. This php page, should make the mysql insert / update.

see : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

So, here is a fast version of what your javascript function will look like:

"Need some implementation"

```
   <?php
echo
"<script>
$(function() {
  $('.my-rating').starRating({
    initialRating: ". $current_rating .",
    callback: function(currentRating, element){
        window.alert('RATED');

        //AJAX CALL to page, passing currentRating

        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: currentRating,
        success: function () {
          alert('currentRating was saved');
        }
      });
    }
  });
}); 
</script>";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the current value to your script (via GET or POST)
It is easy with jQuery

see : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```html
<?php
echo
"<script>
$(function() {
  $('.my-rating').starRating({
    initialRating: ". $current_rating .",
    callback: function(currentRating, element){
        window.alert('RATED');
        $.post( \"your_file_to_save.php\", { ratting : currentRating }, 
                     function( data ) {
                         alert( "RESPONSE : " + data );
                      }
        );
    }
  });
}); 
</script>";?>
```